# How to run my Google Colab notebook on more powerful server

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

The free resource provided by the Google Colab isn't enough for my use case.

Is there a way to spin more powerful GPU/TPU with more memory and to use it for my Colab notebook in Google Cloud? It doesn't have to be Google Cloud though as long as I can run Jupyter notebook easily. I am using Keras/Tensorflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instructions are in the section 'Connecting to a runtime on a Google Compute Engine instance' on this page:
https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Reproducing here:

> If the Jupyter notebook server you'd like to connect to is running on
>   another machine (e.g. Google Compute Engine instance), you can set up
>   SSH local port forwarding to allow Colaboratory to connect to it.
>
> Note: Google Cloud Platform provides Deep Learning VM images with
>   Colaboratory local backend support preconfigured. Follow the how-to
>   guides to set up your Google Compute Engine instance with local SSH
>   port forwarding. If you use these images, skip directly to Step 4:
>   Connect to the local runtime (using port 8888).
>
> First, set up your Jupyter notebook server using the instructions
>   above.
>
> Second, establish an SSH connection from your local machine to the
>   remote instance (e.g. Google Compute Engine instance) and specify the
>   '-L' flag. For example, to forward port 8888 on your local machine to
>   port 8888 on your Google Compute Engine instance, run the following:
>
> ```
> gcloud compute ssh --zone YOUR_ZONE YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
> ```
>
> Finally, make the connection within Colaboratory by connecting to the forwarded port (follow the same instructions under Step 4: Connect
>   to the local runtime).